# Sharepoint 2010 permissions repeatedly revoking

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, permissions

I have a Sharepoint 2010 Enterprise edition farm that we primarily use as an intranet, and random groups (and individuals) permissions keep revoking on random sites.  This morning I came in and apparently all NT Authority/Authenticated Users had been locked out of our intranet homepage (top level).

There have been daily incidents like this, especially on content I have migrated from our old 2007 intranet.  The shared rosters that need to be edited on a daily basis, and the permissions for the group that does that needs to removed and added back in on a daily basis, which resolves the issue.

How do I make my permissions changes "stick" for more than 24 hours?

Thanks in advance

Comment: do you know if you have any background tasks? or tools? 
also, are you using this group for any service, etc?

Comment: Unfortunately It's not just one group, it's random groups and sometimes random people.  It happens at different times.  We have a backup script that runs every night but that's a powershell script that runs off the task scheduler.

Are those the kind of background tasks you're talking about?

Comment: How did you solve this in the end? I've just come across the same issue!

Comment: I'm afraid the solution ended up being a bit non technical.  I waited until after hours and ripped every single permission out from SP and re-entered them in a properly structured way, and it worked.  Not great, but effective.  Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

You will have to find out whats changing the permissions first, look into event logs and try to find clue as you cant find a solution with out knowing the problem.

second if you want a quick fix, just create a sharepoint timer job that checks permissions for every morning and also change it if needed but for that you will have to do some coding

You can setup audit logging in sharepoint that will show you when permissions changed

[audit setting enabled](http://www.sharepointedutech.com/2011/02/14/setting-up-audit-logging-in-sharepoint-2010/)

Comment: Thanks for this.
Any keywords I should look for in the logs?